# Send List with Class objects from form2 to form1

Tags: c#

What I want to do is create a loginapplication where you can register (username and password) and then  log in.
The registration is in form2, what I want to do here is type in a username and a password which should be saved in my personlist. I've been trying to figure out how to use this same list in form1, and to my understanding the class must be static, so I can use it in all my future forms? Code below.

```
namespace windowssomething
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static class Holder 
    {
        public static List<Person> personlist = new List<Person>();

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Pass { get; set; }

            public Person(string name = " ", string pass = " ") 
            {
                Name = name;
                Pass = pass;
            }

            public string Ts()
            {
                string s = "";
                s += Name;
                s += " ";
                s += Pass;

                return s;
            }

        }

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void reg_button_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Holder.Person p1 = new Holder.Person();

        p1.Name = textBox1.Text;
        p1.Pass = textBox2.Text;

        Holder.personlist.Add(p1);

        this.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(p1.Ts());

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}}
```

I've also read the class cant have getters and setters when static, this is where im stuck. So if I make the class static the gets and sets wont work, is there any way around this?

Comment: not a static class. A static instance of the class - quite a different thing.

Comment: *"my understanding the class must be static"* *"I've also read the class cant have getters and setters when static"*  Where are you reading this nonsense? Seems like you need a different book. :)

Comment: stackoverflow to be honest:) been sitting with this code for like 10h now maybe its just to much info at the same time. So, is there a smart way to do this? I dont really understand how to do a static instance.

Comment: you want a static instance of a normal class, not a static class. These are 2 totally different things

Answer (score 1):

The forms are really just UI. The Person and Holder classes are not, so they shouldn't really live in `form2`.

Move the `Person` and `Holder` classes out into their own classes, separate from `form2` or each other.

Person.cs:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    public Person(string name = " ", string pass = " ")
    {
        Name = name;
        Pass = pass;
    }

    public string Ts()
    {
        string s = "";
        s += Name;
        s += " ";
        s += Pass;

        return s;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in comments, you want your `Holder` class to be a static instance. A nice way of doing this is with a [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx):

Holder.cs:

```
public class Holder
{
    private static Holder _instance;

    private Holder()
    {
        People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public static Holder Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Holder();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access your person list (I've named it `People` in my example) from anywhere in your program by: `Holder.Instance.People`, so your click method to add a person might now look like this:

```
private void regButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var person = new Person
    {
        Name = userTextBox.Text,
        Pass = passTextBox.Text
    };

    Holder.Instance.People.Add(person);

    this.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(person.Ts());
}
```